# Can I do database deployments, without installing Visual Studio or VSTSDB?

Tags: tfs, build, visual-studio-dbpro

In setting up our TFS 2010 build machine we are trying to avoid installing Visual Studio (2005/2008/2010). For most builds just installing the necessary SDK has allowed us to get good builds w/o visual studio.

However, with VSTSDB (Visual Studio Team System Database for professionals) I'm unable to identify what (if any) SDK is available to be installed rather than installing VSTSDB on the build machine. Does such an SDK exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TFS 2010 Build Service can build Database Projects out-of-the-box. It doesn't require any additional components.

Comment: per the MSDN forum, I received a response that this is true for tfs2010 and vs2010, but not for tfs2010 and vs2008.  Do you understand this to be the case as well?

Comment: @BozoJoe: yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deploy a database project from the command line, is to use the VSDBCMD utility.

The install process is as simple copying some binaries onto your build machine.
This negates having to install Visual Studio or TFS.

This comes in very handy, where you might be doing manual/adhoc installs on machines where team foundation server isn't installed.

Microsoft recommend this too, see:
[How to: Prepare a Database for Deployment From a Command Prompt by Using VSDBCMD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193258.aspx)

**Note:**
Ensure you read the section titled *Special Requirements for 64-bit Operating Systems*, as you will need to install the correct versions of SQL Server CE for this to work correctly.